# Filtering for different conditions in different columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python 3.9 and Pandas 1.3.4

So here's the df:

```
1   First Name  Last Name  fullname
2   Freddie     Mercury    Freddie Mercury
3   John        Lennon     John Lennon
4   David       Bowie      David Bowie
5                          John Doe
6   Joseph                 Joseph
7               Jovi       Jovi
```

My piece of code currently just finds the `fullname` column is just `First Name` + `Last Name`.

I'm currently trying to filter for blank entries in the `First Name` column, `Last Name` column, and any "John Does" in the `fullname` column.

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str, header=0)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['First Name', 'Last Name', 'fullname'])

df['fullname'] = (df[['First Name', 'Last Name']].fillna('').agg(' '.join, axis=1).str.strip().replace('', 'John Doe'))

df_sort = df2.loc[df2['First Name'] == " "] | df2.loc[df2['Last Name'] == " "] | df2.loc[df2['fullname'] == "John Doe"]


df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
df_sort.to_csv('missing names.csv', index=False)
```

Currently I am having the missing names write to a new file and outputs only this:

```
First Name   Last Name   fullname
```

Everything is empty under.

I would like for the output to be:

```
First Name   Last Name   fullname
                         John Doe
Joseph
             Jovi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace possible missing values to empty string, compare and test if at least one value match in [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df_sort = df2[df2[['First Name', 'Last Name']].fillna('').eq('').any(axis=1)]
```

Or if there are missing values use:

```
df_sort = df2[df2[['First Name', 'Last Name']].isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.loc` at each condition but you need to add some `( )`:

```
>>> df2[(df2['First Name'] == " ")
        | (df2['Last Name'] == " ")
        | (df2['fullname'] == "John Doe")]

  First Name Last Name  fullname
3        NaN       NaN  John Doe
4     Joseph       NaN    Joseph
5        NaN      Jovi      Jovi
```

Note: adapt your missing values to your code. Here I use `== " "` (blank space) like you but you can use `== ""` (empty string) or use `.isna()` (missing values).